# NSManagedObject crashing on NSOperation (ARC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, exc-bad-access, nsoperation

I was converting my project to ARC, and when I reached some `NSOperation` subclasses responsible for downloading some images in background, the code began to crash.

So I have my `NSOperation` subclass and its main code:

```
- (void)main
{
    Post *p = [[Post alloc] initWithNewManagedObjectContext];
    Post *post = (Post *)[p findById:postId];
    [post downloadAndProcessImageOfTypeThumbOrAll:thumbOrAll];

    if (![self isCancelled]) {
        [target performSelectorOnMainThread:afterCompletionAction withObject:postId waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
```

The code works when compiled without **ARC** (and with proper releases), but when it's converted to ARC it received an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** Exception right after finishing the main method.

I guess it is something related to ARC releasing any object before it should, maybe the Posts objects. But I don't know how to retain them longer.

Also, `[[Post alloc] initWithNewManagedObjectContext];` creates or reuses an existing context to access the object from CoreData.

Any hints?

Comment: Run instruments with `NSZombiesEnabled`.  This helps a lot with these kinds of problems.

Comment: What is target? Are you keeping a strong reference to it? If you have no strong reference it will be deallocated immediately, before `performSelectorOnMainThread:` can run... Which means you will be sending a message to a deallocated object.

Comment: `post` will also be deallocated unless you have a reference to it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, a friend helped me to find the issue.
Thanks to every comment.

The problem was with the `NSManagedObjectContext`, which was being accessed by a background thread.

The solution was creating a new context for the background thread, and the trick used was store the context on the `threadDictionary` to be accessed by other background threads, if need.

So now, the `[[Post alloc] initWithNewManagedObjectContext];` creates a separate context:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = nil;
NSThread *thread = [NSThread currentThread];
managedObjectContext = [[thread threadDictionary] valueForKey:@"managedObjectContext"];

if (!managedObjectContext) {
    GTCoreData *gtcd = [[GTCoreData alloc] init];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [gtcd persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        [[thread threadDictionary] setValue:managedObjectContext forKey:@"managedObjectContext"];
    }
}

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
Post *post = [[Post alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
return post;
```